# What is this question in laymen terms, and how do I interpret it? "What is x in terms of a if the product $x*(a-x)$ is a maximum?"

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

Not sure if this is an appropriate math question because it's to do more with comprehension(my lack thereof).

From the answer, it seems like the question is asking "for the maximum value" x in terms of a. Although it doesn't state this outright.

- How do we interpret this question without having first seen the answer..?
- Where does the first sentence, $a=x+(a-x)$ come into play solving this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually in the context of calculus, if someone is asking for the maximum, they want to know the largest possible value of a given quantity. In this case, that quantity is $x \cdot (a-x)$. Note that in this quantity, we think of $a$ as being a fixed value. This means the quantity varies only when $x$ varies too.

So the question is asking you: what is the value of $x$ that gives you the maximum possible value of $x \cdot (a-x)$ (the quantity)?

I'm not sure what relevance the sum has; it's trivial and not needed to complete the problem. (trivial in the sense that even if they hadn't said it, I'm sure you can immediately see it's true!)

Comment: I wish they would just say that...! or at least not add that red herring line... Thank you

Comment: @olif9837 Don't worry, it'll get easier and easier to decipher!

Answer (score 2):

You can interpret that you have a stick of fixed lenght, $a$. Then the question is how can you break it in two in such a way that you can construct the rectangle with the bigger area.